# How to separate several columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with key-value pairs like

```
df <- data.frame(V_1 = c("name:B", "name:c", "name:d", "name:a", "name:k","name:A"),
                 V_2 = c("name:X", "name:Y", "name:Z", "name:K", "name:L","name:K"))
```

and I want to split the columns so that new columns are generated based on the cell inputs separated by :

For a single column I would use

```
df2 <- separate(df, col=V_1, into=paste("C", 1:18, sep = "_"), sep=":", remove = TRUE)
```

But separate() does not work with multiple columns - is that a way to iterate the separate command across multiple columns?

note that for my real dataframe I have several hundred columns, so I am looking for a solution that does not require typing the column names but automatically generates V_n column names and then runs separate on my dataframe.

The expected output is:

```
df2 <- data.frame(C_1 = c("name", "name", "name", "name", "name","name"),
                 C_2 = c("B", "c", "d", "a", "k","A"),
                 C_3 = c("name", "name", "name", "name", "name","name"),
                  C_4 = c("X", "Y", "Z", "K", "L","K"))
df2
```

Comment: Could you please show your expected output?

Comment: expected output now added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `separate_wider_delim()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(cols = everything(),
                       delim = ":",
                       names_sep = "",
                       names_repair = ~ paste("C", seq_along(.x), sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  C_1   C_2   C_3   C_4  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 name  B     name  X    
2 name  c     name  Y    
3 name  d     name  Z    
4 name  a     name  K    
5 name  k     name  L    
6 name  A     name  K
```

If you have other columns in your data frame you can use `matches()` to match a pattern and rename afterwards:

```
df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(cols = matches("^V_\\d+$"),
                       delim = ":",
                       names_sep = "") %>%
  rename_with(~paste0("C_", seq_along(.x)), .cols =  matches("^V_\\d+$"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example I posted, but with columns with other data-structure/types it does not seem to work as well and ouputs a "too few error" -- is there a way to modify this solution to target columns named V_1 to V_n?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot.  Could you also explain the syntax used "^V_\\d+$"? How in the world does this expression end up selecting V_1 to V_n columns?

Comment: It's a simple regex that means match any column names that begin with `V_` followed by and ending with any number of digits. However, you probably could get away with just `starts_with("V_")`.